# after using pinentry-curses (emacs, osx, gpg) key mappings in terminal (iterm2) are broken

Tags: macos, emacs, ncurses, gnupg, iterm2

Did anybody come across that annoying phenomenon that after using pinentry-curses (emacs, osx, gpg) key mappings in terminal (iterm2) are broken?

Before entering a passphrase, e.g. arrow-keys work fine with emacs run in terminal but after entering a passphrase the arrow-keys are unmapped and emacs complains: 
     M-[ a is undefined